# How can I request json data

Tags: python, request

I have Json data. I want to request for urls. But I can see only content data. How can I request Url

JSON DATA:

```
{
"totalElements": 3143,
"totalPages": 158,
"page": 0,
"size": 20,
"content": [{
            "approved": false,
            "images": [{
                "url": "http://example.com/imageurl.jpg"
            }]
        }
```

Python code:

```
import requests
import json
supplierIdInputValue = 12345 #Enter supId
url = "http://example.com/requestdataurl" + str(supplierIdInputValue) + "&size=100"
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/json"
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
spmdata = json.loads(response.text)
for spmdata in spmdata["content"]:
    images = str(spmdata["images"])
    print(images)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately I don't understand your question. Please read [ask] for tips on asking questions effectively.

Comment: what exactly goes wrong here? what is `response.text`?

Comment: text is format for response. I can see [{'url': 'http://example.com/imageurl.jpg}] but I want only http://example.com/imageurl.jpg. This data in images tag. I use this code but not work. 
Code:
 for images in images["url"]:
        link = str(images["url"])
        print(link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)`

After the line above, try:

```
j = response.json()

for c in j['content']:
    for i in c['images']:
        print(i['url'])
```

Maybe that works for you. Also, you seem to be constructing the URL query string manually, but `requests` library can take care of that for you if you give the `params` parameter a Python dictionary as argument.

Comment: Thanks it's work. The parameter must be changed manually. Because we have different data for all supplier

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you may have a problem with decoding the response. You can try the `json()` method called on the response, see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content